# Query (Return) All Points In Query Task and Query Object

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, query-task

Using ArcGIS JavaScript API 3.21 I need to grab all Points on a Server. The code works for me with `Query.where` clause at

> query.where = "FeederID  = 'RMT001'";

but as I said I need to get all Points. I tried to run the query without any `Query.where` statement but not getting back anything. can you please let me know how to get all Points?

```
    function execute () {
       var query = new Query();
       query.where = "FeederID  = 'RMT001'";
       query.returnGeometry = true;
       query.outFields = [ "CreationUser", "FName" ];
       queryTask.execute(query, showResults);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The most common way and which should always work (because it's always true) is 1=1.

> query.where = "1=1";

Using OBJECTID as suggested in another answer, will not work for all layers, see for example https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/incidents_report/FeatureServer/0/ where the "Object ID field" is called FID.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to get geometries, you can use this query :
`query.where = "OBJECTID > 0";`
Arcgis stores geometries with a unique numerical field